# Correction of inflated p values

Tags: p-value, bias

I have thousands of p-values and they are far from being uniform distributed - because of heavy pre-filtering (as an example, we can look at proportion test - if one cell value is less than X, people do not test at all since they think that data is not credible) most of the p-values are bigger than 0.05. How can I correct for pre-filtering bias?

These values are used in a "deserve a second look" manner, not for decision-making. If dataset comes and less than 0.05 of overall amount of p-values (which is, as I said, thousands) are less than 0.05 - this dataset is not even considered for further examination, and I feel that a lot of things are lost due to this filtering.

Moreover, datasets where amount of p-values which are less than 0.05 is way more than 0.05 look less credible for me (it means test assumptions were violated so even this pre-filtering could not correct this violation) - how can I put new level of significance for such "inflated despite pre-filtering" datasets?

UPD: Clarification on actual data. P-values are obtained from Next Generation Sequencing data and proportion test. Assume we read the same genomic part $n_1$ times. $a$ times we had letter A, $n_1 - a$ times we had letter B. Then we have another experiment, we read same genomic part $n_2$ times, $b$ times we had letter A, $n_2 - b$ we had letter B. We want to test if this position is "balanced", so we make contingency table from these 4 values and perform chi-squared or Fisher exact test. $n_{\{1,2\}}$ are usually around 30. The problem is - if $a$ or $b$ are too small (e.g. less than 3), it is considered as an "error" and they do not test this variant at all - because these $a$ and $b$ become undistinguishable from technical errors. Thus, after making thousands of tests, we remove the most extreme cases and get p-values inflated to the right part.

Comment: P-values for binomial tests are not necessarily uniform under the null hypothesis. What are sample sizes? From exactly what test of proportions do these P-values arise. What null hypothesis? What alternative? // We need to know the actual theoretical dist'n of your P-values before we can judge whether 'pre filtering' has altered them.

Comment: updated! The test is usual chi squared or Fisher, depending on expected values.